# Accepting Form Elements As Method Arguments?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a method that will take a screenshot of a passed form element, and print it out.  There are a few challenges I am facing. I want to be able to make this method generic enough to accept just about any type of form element.  I set the "element" argument to type "object".  I think I will also need to pass a "type" argument or is there a way to figure out what type the object is after it is passed?

```
static public void PrintFormElement(object element, ?type?){

}
```

Am I approaching this problem the right way? Any advice would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: What do you say we edit your title here to better reflect the problem at hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that your `element` should be `Control`, and every `Control` has `DrawToBitmap()` method that you can use to take 'screenshot' of it.

So you can forget all about type parameter, because you won't need it, because of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_polymorphism).

Comment: Hey, that's pretty good.  Now I'm kind of curious, this is working fine except for one thing.  When I try to print a richTextBox, if there is text inside of the box, it doesn't actually print.  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4):

You can find out what type something is either using the `is/as` operators, or using `GetType`. It's usually a bit of a design smell if you have to use them though. What are you planning to do that's type-specific?

If you're talking about visual elements, you might want to use `Control` instead of `object`.

Answer (score 1):

I think `object` is too generic, I'd go for [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) instead. You don't need to pass in the type though, you can just query it for it's type using `is`.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answers suggesting to use the Control base class. I'd make your function an extension method to avoid creating ASDFHelper, ASDFUtility and other classes full of static methods.

```
static public void PrintFormElement(this Control element){
    element.DrawToBitmap();
}
```

This can then be invoked like this

```
new TextBox().PrintFormElement();
```